# Cakephp 3 giving me Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cake\Http\Server' not found

Tags: php, cakephp, php-7, cakephp-3.3, php-7.1

I have done a cakephp 2 to cakephp 3 upgrade, and that was causing problems, so I found I had to replace the app/webroot with a new set of files that were part of the cakephp 3 skeleton, but now I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cake\Http\Server' not found in /usr/share/nginx/html/web/app/webroot/index.php:33 Stack trace: #0 /usr/share/nginx/html/web/index.php(47): require() #1 {main} thrown in /usr/share/nginx/html/web/app/webroot/index.php on line 33
```

After some research, I found this page: `https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/`, which shows the classes that should be availabe, and I found that if I go to `my_cake_project/web/lib/Cake` and run `ls` I get:

basics.php  bootstrap.php  config  Configure  Controller  Error  I18n         Log    Network  src   tests      Utility      View
bin         Cache          Config  Console    Core        Event  LICENSE.txt  Model  Routing  Test  TestSuite  VERSION.txt

But I am missing several libraries that are supposed to be in CakePHP 3, including the Http folder, and I believe that is why Cake/Http/Server is not found.

I have tracked down the line that is triggering the error to this:

```
// Bind your application to the server.
$server = new Server(new Application(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config'));
```

This is in app/webroot/index.php.

I tried splitting that up to:

```
$a = new Application(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config');
$server = new Server($a);
```

just for testing, and I found that it is also saying that the `Class Application` can not be found.

This is the whole file of app/webroot/index.php that I have:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Front Controller for handling every request
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since         0.2.9
 * @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */
// for built-in server
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server') {
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = '/' . basename(__FILE__);

    $url = parse_url(urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    $file = __DIR__ . $url['path'];
    if (strpos($url['path'], '..') === false && strpos($url['path'], '.') !== false && is_file($file)) {
        return false;
    }
}
require dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendors/autoload.php';

use App\Application;
use Cake\Http\Server;

// Bind your application to the server.
$server = new Server(new Application(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config'));

// Run the request/response through the application
// and emit the response.
$server->emit($server->run());
```

So I must be missing the file for the Application class too

And based on comparing what I have in `lib/Cake` folder with `https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/` I a missing a bunch of cakephp lib folders.

I seem to be missing not just `Http`, but also:

```
`Auth`, `Collection`, `Database`, `Datasource`, `Filesystem`, `Form`, `Mailer`, `ORM`, `Shell`, `Utility`, and `Validation`
```

Why am I missing these?, and where or how can I find and install all the missing libraries into my cakephp appliation?

Comment: The updrage tool only handles a few aspects of upgrading things, many things still have to be done manually. And there's a chance that you didn't upgrade things correctly of course, many people for example do not realize that the upgrade tool is a standalone application. There is no `lib` folder anymore, dependencies, including the CakePHP core, are now managed via composer, and are to be found in the `vendors` folder.

Comment: You may be better off seeking help in the [**CakePHP forums**](http://discourse.cakephp.org/) or on [**IRC**](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=cakephp)/[**Slack**](http://cakesf.herokuapp.com/), where you can have a more lengthy discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't downloaded all dependencies to vendor folder.
I used OpenServer console on Windows and 
`php composer.phar update` was helpful for me (I had installed composer locally to my project before).
In my opinion, that happened because you had installed the framework instance without Administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when I created my project ages ago Composer was still at the early stage so I didn't install CakePHP through it.

To fix it I had to copy the composer.json file from the example template [here](https://github.com/cakephp/app) then ran `php composer.phar update`. Make sure to choose the correct branch where you copy the composer.json file.

Also I used this [tool](https://github.com/dereuromark/upgrade) when migrating. You can use this incase the official upgrade tool doesn't work for you.